# Diaper changing/change

Tags: grammar

1. Do you like diaper changing.
2. Do you like a diaper change.
3. No diaper changing.
4. No diaper change.

Are these all correct and mean the same? (Do I have to either change mean to meaning or does it mean in this sentence?)

Comment: I think 2 would be unlikely (it barely makes sense unless addressed to the baby, who presumably wouldn't understand *any* of the alternatives). And 4 looks like "broken English" (typical of non-native speakers or the cut-down syntax of a hastily-written sign/notice). 1 and 3 are just different ways of using the same gerund-as-noun, preceded by another noun used attributively (which is normal English usage).

Comment: *Change mean to meaning*--what does this mean?

Comment: Do you like changing diapers? Anyway, you should edit your question to confirm if you mean changing a diaper on a baby.

Comment: You *Are these all correct and mean the same?* is also "Broken English". Choose either *Are these all correct and **do they** mean the same?* or *Are these all correct and **is the** meaning the same?*. Both those alternatives are fine, and mean the same thing *(and the meaning is the same)*..

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers for the correction of my question. Here below i see Pazzo's post going against yours, according to what I read. Can you give me your point of view about the situation with Pazzo?

Comment: Again, my answer is to provide two complete sentences that native speakers would actually say. I have no idea what you want to do with your 4 expressions here. I will edit my answer to indicate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand how you want to use any of your 4 statements.

Comment: Personally, I prefer: _Do you **need** a diaper change?_ (From what I remember from my diaper-changing days, no one really _wanted_ one or _liked_ one.)

Comment: Yeah, okay I added "need."

Comment: Thank you, pazzo. What I gather from FumbleFingers is that option 2 and 4 are gramatically incorrect, whereas you consider these are correct ( I am not sure why age difference has an impact on correctness of sentences). Is it what is going on here?

Comment: In fact, I do not understand how you want to use any of your 4 statements (as complete sentences or as phrases put into complete sentenecs or what). That is why I provided two complere sentences that native speakers would actually say. (Forget about the age thing: I was addressing a side issue.)